# Show database information with jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to show values in my database of a certain team when I click on the submit button. I have a code, but it doesn't work so please help!!
Here's my first code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" 
sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-16x16.png" 
sizes="16x16" />
<title>MLB: Major League Baseball</title>
<link href="css folder/MLBstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getteam.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="titel">    

<img class="MLBTitel"  src="./images/MLBtitel.jpg" alt="MLBTitel" >
<div id="titeltekst">
MAJOR LEAGUE BASEBALL
<br>    
</div>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a class= "menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a class= "menu" href="spelers.php">Spelers</a></li>
<li><a id = "active" class= "menu" href="teams.php">Teams</a></li>
<li><a class= "menu" href="wedstrijden.html">Wedstrijden</a></li>
<li><a class= "menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<br><br>        
</div>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "nivardenjoey";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT teamnaam FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$dropdownlist = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$teamnaam = $row['teamnaam'];

$dropdownlist .="<option value='" . $teamnaam . "'>" . $teamnaam . "        
</option>";

}

if(isset($dropdownlist)){

echo "<select name='teamlijst' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>";
echo $dropdownlist;
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</select>";
}

?>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my second code of the retrieving part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "nivardenjoey";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";
$con = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamnaam = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>teamnaam</th>
<th>coach</th>
<th>info</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['teamnaam'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['coach'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['info'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I really hope anyone can help me

[image: Database]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you type the url directly in your browser's address bar does anything display?

Comment: @DonovanM well this is what I get, but I can't get the actual values from the database [link](http://mlb-site.netne.net/teams.php)

Comment: Oh, I meant the url with `getteam.php?=`. Is that showing you what you expected?

Comment: Actually, I think I see the problem. You have a line with `$q = intval($_GET['q']);`. I don't think you want that to actually be an integer.

Comment: @DonovanM Nope, that is showing this: [link](http://mlb-site.netne.net/getteam.php)

Comment: @DonovanM Yeah that's true, but I'm not sure to which value I need to change the q, because I'm actually still a php noob lol

Comment: For testing purposes change that line to `$q = $_GET['q']` and see if it works. However, don't keep it that way because that can allow sql injections. To avoid those you should [bind it to a prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @DonovanM Well that didn't work, but I guess the q should change to the dropdownlist value called teamlijst, so I guess it will become `$q =  ($_GET['teamlijst'])` but I'm not sure. Maybe you can confirm that.

Comment: The value of `$q` should become `'teamlijst'` after the line with `$q = $_GET['q']`. It might help to put `echo $q` after that line and `echo $sql` after `$sql` is assigned so you can see if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: When I put `echo $q` and `echo $sql` down there this is what I get: 0SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamnaam = '0' so that means that q = 0?

Comment: Yes, `$q` = 0. It sounds like it's still being turned into an integer. Is this happening with `intval` removed?

Comment: @DonovanM No it isn't happening with the `intval` removed, but now I can't get the values in my table. So this is what I get now: [link](http://mlb-site.netne.net/teams.php)

Comment: Hmm. The rest of your code looks fine. Are you able to verify that, for example, `SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamnaam = 'Astros'` works manually? Or you can echo `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to see if you're getting any results from the database.

Comment: @DonovanM Bad luck.. It doesnt work when I enter that manually. The website shows this then [link](http://mlb-site.netne.net/getteam.php)

Comment: unrelated to the question, why aren't you using prepared statements? it's 2017 for crying out loud..

Comment: @flex_ as I already said I'm quite a php noob so I don't really know which prepared statement I need to use and where.

Comment: @NivardJ prepared statements aren't rocket science just google mysqli prepared statement and read the first article that pops up and  viola your webapp is way more secure now. it literally takes less than 10 minutes to get started with prepared statements

Comment: @NivardJ in regards to your previous reply - you'll probably have to play around in phpMyAdmin or whatever you use to see what the proper query should be. Make sure that in your `teams` table the values in `teamnaam` match the values in your dropdown (it's case-sensitive).

Comment: @DonovanM I've attached a screenshot of my database to the post and as far as I can see there's nothing wrong with the values

Comment: Everything looks correct. I'm honestly not sure why it isn't working, unfortunately :(

Comment: @DonovanM Well shit, last thing I can try is to use the prepared statements right? And I really appreciate your help btw :)

Comment: No problem. I was really hoping to get things working haha. Yeah you should probably use prepared statements for the security benefits alone. It would be pretty easy for someone to mess with your db the way you have it now. Also, be sure to change your db credentials if you're currently using what you pasted in your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end I didn't even need 2 files. It's just one file now and this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"                                                 sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./images/favicon-16x16.png"     sizes="16x16" />
<title>MLB: Major League Baseball</title>
<link href="css folder/MLBstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="titel">    

<img class="MLBTitel"  src="./images/MLBtitel.jpg" alt="MLBTitel" >
<div id="titeltekst">
MAJOR LEAGUE BASEBALL
<br>    
</div>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a class= "menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a class= "menu" href="spelers.php">Spelers</a></li>
<li><a id = "active" class= "menu" href="teams.php">Teams</a></li>
<li><a class= "menu" href="wedstrijden.php">Wedstrijden</a></li>
<li><a class= "menu" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<br><br>        
</div>
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT teamnaam FROM teams";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$dropdownlist = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$teamnaam = $row['teamnaam'];

$dropdownlist .="<option value='" . $teamnaam . "'>" . $teamnaam . "    </option>";

}

if(isset($dropdownlist)){
echo "<form action='teams.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<select name='teamlijst'>";
echo $dropdownlist;
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["teamlijst"])){
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM teams WHERE teamnaam = '" . $_POST["teamlijst"] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>teamnaam</th>
<th>coach</th>
<th>info</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['teamnaam'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['coach'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['info'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm unable to make comment

you need to change your servername to localhost

also you should use firebug for javascript debug

the rest of your code seems fine 
and if you can't get PHP errors you should check you php.ini settings

```
$localhost= "localhost";
$username = "id1419279_root";
$password = "nivardenjoey";
$dbname = "id1419279_mlb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: Good point about the php errors. But how is this code any different from what's already there (other than the typo you made)?

Comment: nothing
But it was strange that he did not mention any errors

Answer (score 0):

1.Your `$row` is not defined while you were using `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`, im wondering whether this `while` was working.

2.Try `dump` your SQL results to check if your database settings was going right.

Comment: How do I check if the `while` is working? And where to dump my sql?